# First time NFC read doesn't work

Tags: ionic2, nfc

I have to read a NFC tag with ionic 2, the problem is the first attempt doesn't read then if I read again is working fine. I initialize nfc listener in platform.ready() I think that this should be enough...

This is my code:

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-dispositivo',
templateUrl: 'dispositivo.html',
providers: [NFC, Ndef, Diagnostic, Vibration]
})
export class DispositivoPage {

subscriptions: Array<Subscription> = new Array<Subscription>();

constructor(
  public navCtrl: NavController,
  public navParams: NavParams,
  private auth: AuthService,
  public loading: LoadingController,
  public alertCtrl: AlertController,
  public toastCtrl: ToastController,
  private nfc: NFC,
  private ndef: Ndef,
  public diagnostic: Diagnostic,
  public platform: Platform,
  public vibration: Vibration
) {

  platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.initNFC();
  });
}

initNFC() {
  this.nfc.enabled()
    .then(() => {
      this.addListenNFC();
    }).catch(err => {
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        subTitle: 'Active la conexión NFC para para leer artículos',
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'Activar más tarde',
            handler: () => {    
              this.goToHome();
            }
          },
          {
            text: 'Ir a Ajustes para activar',
            handler: () => {
              this.nfc.showSettings().then(rs => {
                this.goToHome();
              });
            }
          }]
      });
      alert.present();
    });
}

addListenNFC() {
  this.subscriptions.push(this.nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener().subscribe(nfcData => {
    this.processResponse(nfcData);
  }));
}
```

I don't know what is happening, somebody can help me?